# jasper reports issues with fixed page height

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report with dynamic subreports and a page footer that should stick to the bottom of the page. The problem is that the text is dynamic and some pages have more text, some other pages have less text. When the page has less text it pulls the page footer up and when the page has more text, it pushes the page footer down. I have specified the page height property `pageHeight` and I have placed my stuff in a band in `pageFooter`. I have tried using the `background` instead of `pageFooter` and this actually forces the page to have a constant height and it works fine except a tiny little detail that kills the entire solution. In some reports it prints the header of the table alone at the end of the page like in this image: [image]

If I use the `pageFooter` the header of the table does not appear alone. It appears only when I use `background`. It seems to me as if when I force the page to the maximum height, it causes the head of the table to appear alone. The report is huge. It spans tens of xml files. I don't think it is a good idea to post it. And the xml is full of java code. I will post portions of it upon request, if that helps you  get a better idea. I hope I explained the issue clear enough. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance,

Corneliu

Comment: Have you tried using the "Detail" band?

Comment: Thank you Endrik. I am not sure i understand what you asked. Only the last line is the footer. The table and the text above it is from a subreport that lives in the detail section. Now if you asked me to put the last line, the one that starts with "TER10..." (which is the footer) in the detail, then how is it going to be generated at the bottom of each page?

Comment: I should also mention that when I use the `pageFooter` and I export to pdf, then the page footer's position is OK. But when I print directly from the Jasper Viewer then the footer's position varies from page to page. If I use the `background` then when i print, the footer's position is always the same, which is what i want.

Comment: When I export the report to pdf and print from pdf, then the footer position is good. It's only when the report is printed directly from Jasper Viewer that the footer position varies from page to page. The main point is to be able to print the report properly, so the pdf workaround solves the issue. Should i answer my own question and mark it solved, even if this is no solution, but just a workaround?